# Find clients who have not placed an order in the past 18 months

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql db with client orders and I am using client email addresses to distinguish between different clients. I would like to find all clients who have not ordered in the past 18 months. To be clear, I do not want to list all orders that were placed more than 18 months ago but only find those clients (removing duplicates based on emails) who have not placed an order within the past 18 months.

Example 1: a client who placed an order 2 years ago and then placed another order 1 year ago should not appear in the results of this query.
Example 2: a client who placed an order 3 years ago and another one 2 years ago should appear in the results but only once.

Here an example Table

```
| order_id | client_name | client_email | order_date |
|---------:|:-----------:|:------------:|:----------:|
| 1        | Peter Pan   | m1@mail.com  | 2022-11-02 |
| 2        | John Doe    | t1@mail.com  | 2021-11-02 |
| 3        | Jane Doe    | j1@mail.com  | 2020-11-02 |
| 4        | Peter Pan   | m1@mail.com  | 2020-10-22 |
| 5        | Jane Doe    | j1@mail.com  | 2019-10-22 |
| 6        | John Doe    | t1@mail.com  | 2018-10-22 |
```

For this example, the query should yield only 1 result.

> Jane Doe j1@mail.com

Because both Peter Pan and John Doe have ordered within the past 18 months.

Comment: Please show us actual data, along with the results you want. Also, what query did you try so far - even if it did not work as you expected.

Comment: @GMB Tbh I would not know where to start. I imagine you need 2 separate queries: (1) get all orders placed >18 months ago and remove duplicates based on email. (2) find all orders placed <18 months ago and remove duplicates based on emails. Then subtract query (2) from query (1). I am just not sure how to express this in mysql. For arguments sake let's say the columns are called: order_id, client_name, client_email, order_date. order_id is the primary key and unique.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service or tutorial site. This sort of thing can be found in a good SQL tutorial or book, as it's a relatively basic query. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties, but you are expected to make that effort first.

Comment: @Ken White As I said, I am not sure how to do it and if it is only a 1 line query as you say, wouldn't it have been quicker to simply type that line than an entirely unhelpful paragraph? Just wondering.

Comment: Nope. Not my job to enable people to avoid learning. As I said, we're not a code writing service.

Comment: @KenWhite Simply: Wow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is written without a db, so let's hope it's right.

```sql
select distinct o1.client_email, o1.client_name from orders as o1
where (select max(order_date) from orders as o2 where o2.client_email = o1.client_email) < NOW() - INTERVAL 18 MONTH
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: it did? nice. ideally sql questions should have a sql fiddle setup to play with... those take time to build but make the answer an easier process.

Comment: Just a quick follow-up. In this query the "distinct" is applied to both the email and name, correct? Because I do get some emails twice in the query results if the clients gave their names slightly differently in different orders (e.g., with or without a middle initial). I want the `distinct` to apply to `client_email` only. I am not sure how to do it in the query itself (I tried placing parenthesis around `distinct o1.client_email` but this gave an error) but I think it works by adding ` GROUP BY o1.client_email ASC` to the end of the query.